# Chart.js not to be begin in Y-Axis

Tags: javascript, chart.js

this is what the code looks like right now
With an 1st image preview currently using Chart.js.

Please give me some insights on how my data chart not to begin in Y axis.

ACTUAL RESULT of the Code below.
[image]

```js
 var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: [<?php echo trim($labels);?>],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Weekly Revenue',
                data: [ 0, 100, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000,9000,10000,],    
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 3
            },
        ]
        },
        options: {
         
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return value.toLocaleString("en-PH",{style:"currency", currency:"PHP"});
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
```

```html
<div class="chart-container"  style="min-width: 210px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
 </div>
```

Aiming:  Data does not begin in Y-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to produce a margin between the Y axis and your first point is to add an empty string spacer in `labels` and a null value in `data`:

```js
{
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: ['', '2020-12-27','2020-12-28','2020-12-29','2020-12-31','2020-12-31','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-04','2020-01-05'],
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Weekly Revenue',
                data: [ null, 0, 100, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000,9000,10000,],    
                fill: false,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 3
            },
        ]
        },
        options: {
         
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return value.toLocaleString("en-PH",{style:"currency", currency:"PHP"});
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: chart.js space on left]

Comment: Thank you, I will take this as an answer. I am currentl fetching the data from my database the first result gives me Invalid date. Should I modify it on my query?